# Setting the last value of each matrix in a cell array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, cell-array

I have a cell array where each cell contains a matrix of identical size. How do I efficiently set the last entry of each matrix in the array? I was trying to make use of `cellfun` but it doesn't look like assignment is possible.

Minimal working example (the most efficient implementation I could come up with):

```
C = cell(5, 6, 7);
[C{:}] = deal(ones(10, 1));
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:6
        for k = 1:7
            C{i,j,k}(end) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Show your code in a minimal working example.

Comment: The loop can be marginally more effective if you use a single loop variable: `for n = 1:numel(C); C{n}(end) = 0; end;`. This is already quite short and well readable, and I doubt you will gain much efficiency using `cellfun` -- while you will likely lose some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to change your original input. Could you live without a cell? These are normally only used when you have heterogeneous data.

Try making each cell a page (where pages are the third dimension) of an array (so now it's now just a vanilla 3D array).

Then you should be able to index directly into the last entry of each page.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Create a function (e.g. in a separate file)

```
function x = assignAtEnd(x, v)
  x(end) = v;
end
```

and perform `cellfun` as follows

```
B = cellfun(@(x) assignAtEnd(x, 0), C, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

This will give you a `B` cell array with all the values at the end changed to 0.

However, I do not think this is a lot faster than the for loop. It might, in fact, be slower. I did a test with 1.000.000 cell elements (100, 100, 100), and the result on my machine was the following

```
for-loop (3D): 3.48 sec
for-loop (1D as per @mikkola): 2.67 sec
cellfun: 3.06 sec
```

### Option 2

If each cell contains a matrix of identical size and your application is time critical, it turns out it is faster to convert the cell array to a numeric array, do the operation, and convert it back to a cell array.

```
% creating the cell
cellDim = 100;
matrixDim = 10;
C = cell(cellDim, cellDim, cellDim);
[C{:}] = deal(1:matrixDim);

% converting to a 4D numeric matrix
A = reshape(cell2mat(C), cellDim, matrixDim, cellDim, cellDim);
% assigning the 0s
A(:,end,:,:) = 0;
% converting back to a cell
B = squeeze(num2cell(A, 2));
```

In fact, the last line of converting back to a cell takes most of the time. The operation in total takes

```
with numeric conversion: 1.93 sec
```

However, `1.40 sec` out of this is taken for conversion back to a cell array, therefore your operation takes only `0.5 sec`, **5 times faster!**

For completeness, I also did a time test on [@LuisMendo's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901243/7510661), and the result is

```
with numeric conversion (@LuisMendo): 1.66 sec
```

### Takeaway message

Avoid cell arrays if you have data of same dimensions! Use numeric arrays of higher dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it without loops. This allows

- the cells to contain a matrix (not necessarily a vector as in your example); and
- the desired values to be different for each cell (not necessarily the same as in your example).

Code:

```
C = repmat({zeros(2,3)}, 4, 5, 6); % example cell array with matrices
values = 1:numel(C); % example vector with numel(C) values. Or it can be a scalar
t = cat(3, C{:}); % temporarily concatenate all matrices into 3D array
t(end,end,:) = values; % set last value of each matrix
C = reshape(num2cell(t, [1 2]), size(C)); % convert back
```

Result:

```
>> whos C
  Name      Size             Bytes  Class    Attributes

  C         4x5x6            19200  cell               

>> C{1,1,1}
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
>> C{2,1,1}
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     0     2
>> C{4,5,6}
ans =
     0     0     0
     0     0   120
```